# Using ConfigService in Unit Test - NestJS

Tags: unit-testing, apache-kafka, nestjs, nestjs-config

I have a Kafka ProducerService which looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProducerService implements OnModuleInit, OnApplicationShutdown {
  private logger = new Logger(ProducerService.name);
  public readonly topic: string;
  private readonly url: string;
  private readonly clientId: string;
  private readonly scramUsername: string;
  private readonly scramPassword: string;
  private kafka: Kafka;
  private producer: Producer;

  constructor(private config: ConfigService) {
    this.url = this.config.get<string>('kafka.brokerUrl');
    this.topic = this.config.get<string>('kafka.topic');
    this.clientId = this.config.get<string>('kafka.clientId');
    if(this.config.get<boolean>('kafka.scram.enabled') == true) {
      this.scramUsername = this.config.get<string>('kafka.scram.username');
      this.scramPassword = this.config.get<string>('kafka.scram.password');
    } else {
      this.scramUsername = "";
      this.scramPassword = "";
    }
    this.kafka = new Kafka({
      brokers: [this.url],
      clientId: this.clientId,
    });
    this.producer = this.kafka.producer();
  }
```

I import the `ConfigModule` in my `KafkaModule`, which allows me to inject `ConfigService` in the `ProducerService` constructor function.

How can I test this service sufficiently?
I am trying something as basic as this in my `producer.spec.ts` file:

```
describe('ProducerService', () => {
  const config = new ConfigService()
  const client = new ProducerService(config)
  
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await client.onModuleInit();
  })

  it('Should connect', () => {
    expect(client).toBeDefined()
  })
```

but I keep failing to load configuration into the test object:

```
KafkaJSNonRetriableError: Failed to connect: broker at index 0 is invalid "undefined"
```

Wrt. config, I am using a `.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Node 16? I had the same issue and I used nvm to switch to Node 14. It works now.

No idea what the actual issue was, but this may help.